# What is the speed of 2 wire pairs to a gigabit switch?

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, gigabit-ethernet

I'm going to be converting my landline (Cat 5e cable) into a LAN setup. The way I plan on having it setup is using one of the plugs as an input that will provide Ethernet through 2 wire pairs and use the other 2 pairs to provide power, because the switch won't be close to any plugs and this is done with a simple POE injector, the power and data are on separate wire pairs. Data will be provided from a gigabit router and the devices that will plug into the LAN network are capable of gigabit speeds.

Then at the other end where all the ethernet cables meet up I plan on having the switch there with a simple POE splitter to provide both power to the switch and data through my input ethernet cable. I was wondering since I will only have 2 wire pairs for data, would having a gigabit switch allow me to get somewhat higher speeds than a 100Mb switch, obviously it wouldn't be gigabit, but I'm just wondering if I would get speeds in-between or is that impossible?

Comment: You probably need to add more information about all hardware involved in you setup. ie; ethernet controllers in each device, etc.

Comment: I added a bit more info, I'm using a gigabit router to provide to the switch and the devices that I will connect to my LAN network are capable of gigabit speeds

Comment: Best guess, since you are not using gigabit protocol on 8 wires the setup will fall back to 4 wire 100mbit.  I guess that you might be able to push more over the wire, but using standard equipment and default settings you probably end up at 100mbit.

Comment: You should post this as an answer I've been doing more and more research and you maybe right after all, as there is nothing to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; there is no speed between 100 and 1000 Mbps.  You need to get gigabit compatible PoE gear, which allows both power and data to travel over all of the wires.

Answer (score 0):

In theory a 1000Base-T chip could establish:

- 250 Mbps over 1 pair
- 500 Mbps over 2 pairs
- 750 Mbps over 3 pairs
- 1000 Mbps over 4 pairs

But that's theory. I heard rumors of devices supporting the 500 Mbps using only the orange and green pairs like 100Base-TX. But I don't know any and I cannot find anything about it so I guess people were confused with the 500 Mbps PowerLineCommunication adapters which have nothing to do with it.

Anyway PoE is supported on Gigabit, but you need a special injector to inject the Voltage on 2 of the 4 data pairs. None of this passive PoE will do. Passive PoE will only work with 10/100Mbps.

Buy a Gigabit compatible PoE injector and extractor and you should get power and Gigabit speeds at the end of your cable. Of course these will come at a price although recent prices are much lower than years ago where passive PoE was the only affordable option for non-business users.